# deleted all the files in usr/bin typing in rm -rf *

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, data-recovery

I'm new to linux and installed Ubuntu 12.04 today. I accidentally deleted everything in `/usr/bin` typing in the command `rm -rf *`.

I don't know what is mounting and would like to learn but at this point I think the only way left for me is to re install everything. Please let me know the ways to re install everything now. It would be of great help to me.

Comment: Think twice next time before typing in some commands, *especially* when running them as root and *especially* for commands like `rm -rf *`...

Comment: @phoibos, lesson learnt. i will delete carefully if need to from next time. i was just too excited today and anything in too much obviously leads to sorrow and philosophy haha..

Comment: How about upgrading the system?

Comment: @nikhil that is a good idea. but i already deleted windows and installed ubuntu in my system

Comment: I meant running `apt-get upgrade`, that might work out not sure that would work though.

Comment: Could copying the files in `/usr/bin` from a live usb work ?

Answer (score 9):

Since you just installed today, do the installation again. While you can recover from this, it'll be a lot more work than redoing the installation.

To recover from the deletion of `/usr/bin`, you would need to reinstall all the packages that have files in that directory. You can use this command to list the affected packages:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
grep -l '^/usr/bin/' *.list | sed 's/\.list$//'
```

You'll then need to find some way of downloading the packages without relying on any of the deleted programs. Since you've deleted `dpkg`, the low-level package installation utility, you'll need to obtain it from somewhere first. Grab it from some other machine running the same release Ubuntu, or download the [`dpkg`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dpkg) package on another machine and extract the programs from it. You'll need not just `/usr/bin/dpkg` but also all the other programs in that package, including `update-alternatives` and all the programs named `/usr/bin/dpkg-*`. Again, copying might be tricky with so many programs deleted, so you may need to reboot to a rescue CD/USB to do it.

Once you have the `dpkg` suite, download at least the [`dpkg`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/dpkg) and [`apt`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/apt) package somehow, perhaps on another machine or in a still-running web browser.

Then install `apt` manually with the command

```
dpkg -i /path/to/apt_0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.2.deb
```

If you get errors about missing commands, reinstall the corresponding packages first. Then reinstall all the affected packages:

```
apt-get --reinstall install $(grep -l '^/usr/bin/' *.list | sed 's/\.list$//')
```

Again, in your situation, just do a complete reinstallation.

Comment: i would definitely go for a re installation. But can i reinstall it on the same 80gb memory i used install the current one?

Comment: @user1455116 Yes, tell the installer to use the existing partition and to erase its content.

Comment: Hm, `which dpkg` says dpkg is in `/usr/bin/dpkg`, so that won't be available...

Comment: @Gilles how do i do that? i already tried restarting with the cd in the drive and splits my current windows memory into two, and does not show the 80gb part :(

Comment: @phoibos Right, thanks, so recovery is likely to require booting to a rescue CD.

Comment: @user1455116 I'm not familiar with the 12.04 installer. Tell it to use custom partitioning.

Answer (score 4):

`/usr/bin/` contains most of the programs that are installed on your system.

Just installing Ubuntu again would be the easiest and fastest way to get a working system again.

Comment: `/usr/bin` contains some programs' executables. Not all programs are there, and their data files are not there either.

Comment: @Florian Diesch Hi i would definitely do that. Now i have windows 7 in one partition and ubuntu in another (80gb). Can i reinstall in the same 80gb space?

Comment: @user1455116 That's the way to go.

Comment: @user1455116 Yes. just be careful to select the right partition when installing.

Comment: @ngel Araya im not having any option saying wipe the current ubuntu and reinstall while i start from the CD, it is creating another partition and a third OS :(

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS: Of course it is possible the rescue the system without reinstalling. It would only take much longer and require some advanced knowledge about system internals.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe export this directory from another computer through NFS? Yes, this is very ugly and you should just reinstall.

Anyway:
mount should still work, because

```
ls /usr/bin | grep mount
```

didn't give me anything besides `grub-mount`. So just copying relevant files from a mounted directory might work temporarily. Just remember, `sudo` will not work, use `su`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really hard if this is a vm:

1. save the list of packages you had installed

   ```
   cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
   grep -l '^/usr/bin/' *.list | sed 's/\.list$//' > ~/packs.txt
   ```
2. Install the same OS version (i386 or amd64) on a new VM
3. On the fresh machine do

   ```
   cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
   grep -l '^/usr/bin/' *.list | sed 's/\.list$//' > ~/packs2.txt
   ```
4. copy the content of `packs.txt` on the new system and you can do:

   ```
   install=$(diff -c ~/packs2.txt ~/packs.txt | grep "^- " | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs echo )
   apt-get install -y --force-yes $install
   remove=$(diff -c ~/packs2.txt ~/packs.txt | grep "^+ " | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs echo )
   apt-get purge -y --force-yes $remove
   ```
5. Now the new system has the same content `/usr/bin` of your damaged machine
6. mount the disk of your broken machine into the new one and finally:

   ```
   rsync -av /usr/bin /mnt/usr/bin
   ```

profit

Answer (score 0):

Had the same foolish problem... here is what I have done to get everything working again:

**1.** Like in the answer of @Gilles, make a list of your packages:

```
cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
grep -l '^/usr/bin/' *.list | sed 's/\.list$//' > ~/my_packages1.txt
```

**2.** Insert a Live CD with the same Ubuntu version, boot from that and copy your `/usr/bin` directory. The partition with Ubuntu on my hard disk was mounted, so that is as easy as

```
cp -R /usr/bin /media/something/usr/bin
```

**3.** Now I couldn't use `sudo` or `pkexec`, because I got the error message *must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set*. So I had to change that, by booting from GRUB into a root shell. (See [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) how to do this and on this [german site](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Recovery-Modus) for some pics.) Now:

```
mount -o remount,rw / 
chown -R root:root /usr/bin
chmod a=rx,u+ws /usr/bin/sudo
chmod a=rx,u+ws /usr/bin/pkexec
```

Reboot into your normal Ubuntu system.

**4.** Reinstall your packages:

```
sudo xargs -a ~/my_packages1.txt apt-get install --reinstall
rm ~/my_packages.txt
```

**5.** There were still many packages missing. `debsums` helped my finding those packages for installing them manually. (Maybe with this step 1 and 4 are obsolete, but I haven't tried...)

```
sudo apt-get install debsums
sudo debsums_init

# This lets debsums find packages with missing files, filters the package names and writes the unique ones to the file.
sudo debsums -cs 2>&1 >/dev/null | sed -e 's/\(.*\)from \(.*\) package\(.*\)/\2/' | uniq -u > my_packages2.txt

sudo xargs -a ~/my_packages2.txt apt-get install --reinstall
```